# How to map request parameter to a bean with different name in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I know Struts 2 make automatic mapping from request parameter to action class fields using `param` interceptor. But what if I want to map a parameter to an action field with different  name. Suppose I have

```
<input type="text" name="username">
```

if I want to map this to the below field

```
private String realName;
public String getRealName() {
return realName;
}

public void setRealName(String realName) {
      this.realNaame = realName;
}
```

How can I do this mapping. Can I use

```
realName = request.getParameter("username");
```

If so how can I get the request object in the action class? Also will it work in the JSP page with the OGNL expression `username` or `realName` ? Is there any other way in struts2 configuration to do this kind of mapping?

Comment: `ServletRequestAware` interface is used to get request object.

Comment: Why do you need other name?

Comment: Usually there is no need for that. But as a learner I want to know is there any way

Answer (score 4):

Use the [alias interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/alias-interceptor.html), nutshell:

```
<action name="someAction" class="com.examples.SomeAction">
    <!-- The value for the foo parameter will be applied as if it were named bar -->
    <param name="aliases">#{ 'foo' : 'bar' }</param>

    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <result>result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: 1+  for the alias interceptor in a nutshell.